# Module to compose,read and reply to emails in Drupal 7

Tags: email, drupal-7

I have a basic set of Drupal 7 installed with PostgreSql.I wanted to implement a module with option to display mail inbox with read and unread mail and an option to compose mail.And all i have to access though API (services).Is their any module available ? The one which suits my need is "Private Message" but not much customization available in that Module.Any example code or recommended learning resources would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: So you want a private messages system? Not working with true e-mail and mail servers, etc...?

Comment: Yes , Private messages system where i have to integrate service API.